# My beans have an al dente texture after cooking. Is this indicitive of undercooking?

Tags: beans

I wouldn't call it hard by mouthfeel, but after using the boil and soak method on some dried pinto beans and cooking in a chili pot for 1.5 hours,

Comment: I'd have given them at least an hour on their own before adding to the chilli if you're trying to rush it, or a whole lot longer then an hour & a half if you drop them straight into a long-cook. Chilli needs 3 hours on a regular simmer, or far more in a slow-cooker, by which time the beans should have caught up.

Comment: Could also be the case that they salted while the beans are cooking - this can leave the beans hard even after hours of cooking. Salt at the end to avoid.